# Selecionar un objeto en una tabla y que un ComboBox con una lista de objetos seleccione el elegido en la tabla (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, listview, combobox

Tengo una tabla que al ser selecionada una fila devuelve un objeto.A su vez tengo un Combobox con una lista de objetos cargada.

Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar un objeto en la lista, el Combobox autoselecione ese objeto en su lista.

Mi código para mostrar la seleección de la lista en el Combobbox:

```
        CmbEmpleado.getSelectionModel().select(ped.getEmpleado());
```

En teoria esto debería de funcionar, porque si hago un print del 'ped.getEmpleado()' me devuelve el objeto correcto, pero en el Combobox no lo selecciona y aparece un blanco.

Comment: según veo estás seleccionando el modelo de la tabla, no el de combobox. ¿te refieres a un javax.swing.JCombobox?

Comment: estoy utilizando javafx, lo que quiero es que el objeto que selecciono en la table se seleccione en el combobox. El objeto seleccionado en la tabla lo extraigo correctamente, pero el combobox que ya contiene ese objeto en la lista no lo selecciona, muestra una selección vacía